# Why is Newtonsoft.Json failing to parse a DateTimeOffset value?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using .NET framework and Newtonsoft.JSON package to serialize my object. I have a `DateTimeOffset` in my object and

{"body":"{  "transactionDate": "2022-02-12T01:22:33+00:00" }"}

causes following error :

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException Error converting value
```

What is wrong in JSON string format?

```
public partial class ConsumeWalletRequest
{
    

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("transactionDate", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Include)]
    public System.DateTimeOffset TransactionDate { get; set; }

}
```

this class is input parameter of an api

```
public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ConsumeWalletResponseApiResultModel> PostConsumeWalletAsync(ConsumeWalletRequest body)
        {
            return PostConsumeWalletAsync(body, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
        }
```

Comment: When you're faced with a submission error due to not including enough information, the right solution *isn't* to copy/paste some of the existing information - it's to add *more* information. Ideally, provide a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem. At that point, you're very likely to get an answer - but I suspect many readers are (like me) reluctant to *guess* what your code looks like and *hope* that they manage to reproduce it that way.

Comment: The format seems to be `DateTimeOffset` compliant. Can you double-check your `transactionDate` property whether it is `DateTimeOffset` and not `DateTime`?

Comment: i don't see where the "body" key of the json is handled. As stated before we need something more complete to get beyond guessing.

Comment: You don't have valid JSON: you have some kind of embedding going on `{"body":"{ "transactionDate": "2022-02-12T01:22:33+00:00" }"}` contains quotes around an incorrectly escaped JSON-stringified object. See repro https://dotnetfiddle.net/jY3wO5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have valid JSON. You have some kind of embedding going on, and it contains quotes around an incorrectly escaped JSON-stringified object.

```json
{"body":"{ "transactionDate": "2022-02-12T01:22:33+00:00" }"}
```

---

If you wanted to correctly escape it you would escape the `"` with `\` (this is separate from C# string quoting).

```json
{"body":"{ \"transactionDate\": \"2022-02-12T01:22:33+00:00\" }}
```

but what you actually want is probably

```json
{"body":{ "transactionDate": "2022-02-12T01:22:33+00:00" }}
```

See [repro here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jY3wO5).

I suggest you check how this JSON is generated, because no good JSON parser would create this.